# Android: Wake up screen from a service

Tags: android, screen

I am working on an android app that listens to the surrounding voices, and executes commands.

One of the commands is waking up the screen.

In order to achieve that goal, I am using the following function, **inside my service**:

```
private void wakeupScreen() {
    new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
        @Override
        protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {
                PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                PowerManager.WakeLock fullWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");
                fullWakeLock.acquire(); // turn on
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(10000); // turn on duration
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                fullWakeLock.release();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return e;
            }
            return null;
        }
    }.execute();
}
```

However, I have several problems with this code: (it runs on a **service**)

- Using `SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK` and `FULL_WAKE_LOCK` is [deprecated](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html).
- The use of AsyncTask and sleep seems like a bad solution for turning the screen on, in non-blocking way.

I wonder if more elegant way exists. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Launch an activity, just to get the screen on under `onCreate()`.

See the discussions at [what is the proper, non-deprecated way to wake up the device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369476/what-is-the-proper-non-deprecated-way-to-wake-up-the-device)

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, there is no elegant way to achieve that goal.

I will summarize my 3 non-elegant solutions to that problem, for future readers:

- Use wakelocks in asynchronously way:

  ```
  private void wakeupScreen() {
      new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Exception>() {
          @Override
          protected Exception doInBackground(Void... params) {
              try {
                  PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
                  PowerManager.WakeLock fullWakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock((PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP), "Loneworker - FULL WAKE LOCK");
                  fullWakeLock.acquire(); // turn on
                  try {
                      Thread.sleep(10000); // turn on duration
                  } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
                  fullWakeLock.release();
              } catch (Exception e) {
                  return e;
              }
              return null;
          }
      }.execute();
  }
  ```
- [Launch an activity that turns the screen on.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246425/turning-on-screen-from-receiver-service)
- [Simulate HOME button click.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2752319/android-simulate-home-click) (similar to solution 2, without the need to create a custom activity, and slightly different behavior)

I found the first solution as the best for my needs.