# Wakelock not working on Nexus 7

Tags: android, wakelock

Hello everybody and thanks in advance for the help and time.

Okay my problem is I have developed an application that shows a notification with a Service.  I had to use a wakelock in order to display the notification when the screen is off.

That works perfectly in my samsung galaxy s4, running lollipop,  but don't work in my Google Nexus 7 running jelly bean, when screen is off, no notification is displayed.

Is this an issue with the Android version? Am I doing something wrong or forgetting something?.

Can anybody help me about this?

Thank you very much.

EDIT:
Sorry, but I hadn`t the code before. Here it is...

```
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.PowerManager;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.text.format.Time;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

public class ServicioRecordatorio extends Service
{
    public static final long INTERVALO_NOTIFICACION = 60 * 1000;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler();

    private Timer mTimer = null;

    PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock;


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate()
    {
        if (mTimer != null)
        {
            mTimer.cancel();
        }
        else
        {
            mTimer = new Timer();
        }

        mTimer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new NotificacionTimerTask(), 0,     INTERVALO_NOTIFICACION);
    }


    class NotificacionTimerTask extends TimerTask
    {
        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MuestraNotificacion();
                }

            });
        }


        private void MuestraNotificacion()
        {
            Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
            today.setToNow();

            SharedPreferences prefs = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("com.tonicc.opositest_preferences", Context.MODE_MULTI_PROCESS);

            Boolean SONIDO_RECORDATORIO_ACTIVADO = prefs.getBoolean("sonidoRecordatorio", false);
            Boolean VIBRACION_RECORDATORIO_ACTIVADA = prefs.getBoolean("vibracionRecordatorio", false);
            String[] HoraMinutos = prefs.getString("horaRecordatorio", "00:00").split(":");

            int Hora = (Integer.parseInt(HoraMinutos[0]));
            int Minutos = (Integer.parseInt(HoraMinutos[1]));

            PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
            wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, "MyWakelockTag");
            wakeLock.acquire();

            if(today.hour == Hora && today.minute == Minutos)
            {
                Uri sonido = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.raw.fin_test);

                int notificacionID = 1;

                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BienvenidaActivity.class);
                i.putExtra("notificacionID", notificacionID);

                PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, i, 0);

                CharSequence ticker = getResources().getString(R.string.ac_servicio_recordatorio_01);
                CharSequence contentTitle = getResources().getString(R.string.ac_servicio_recordatorio_02);
                CharSequence contentText = getResources().getString(R.string.ac_servicio_recordatorio_03);
                CharSequence subText = getResources().getString(R.string.ac_servicio_recordatorio_04);

                NotificationCompat.Builder noti = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());

                noti.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
                noti.setTicker(ticker);
                noti.setContentTitle(contentTitle);
                noti.setContentText(contentText);
                noti.setSubText(subText);
                noti.setSmallIcon(getResources().getIdentifier("icono_app_pequeno", "drawable", getPackageName()));
                noti.addAction(getResources().getIdentifier("icono_app_pequeno", "drawable", getPackageName()), ticker, pendingIntent);
                noti.setAutoCancel(true);

                if(SONIDO_RECORDATORIO_ACTIVADO)
                {
                    noti.setSound(sonido);
                }

                if(VIBRACION_RECORDATORIO_ACTIVADA)
                {
                    noti.setVibrate(new long[]{100, 250, 100, 500});
                }

                Notification n = noti.build();

                NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                nm.notify(notificacionID, n);
            }

            wakeLock.release();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy();

        mTimer.cancel();
    }
}
```

Comment: please post your code and make sure to read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Please, someone who can give an answer, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following `WakeLock` flags to wake up the screen:

```
PowerManager.WakeLock screenOn = ((PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)).newWakeLock(
PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK | PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP, TAG);
screenOn.acquire();
```

This works for me on all devices.

Comment: It works Droidman, though I don't want the screen to turn on when the notification is showed so I removed the ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP. But the curious thing is that the working tag, SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK is deprecated ????. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I still didn't figure it out, refer to [that question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30369476/what-is-the-proper-non-deprecated-way-to-wake-up-the-device) of mine. I guess we have no alternative as it now stands