# When the device is sleep IntentService is not getting called

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service, intentservice, wakelock

I am Triggering an IntentService from WakefullBroadcastReceiver

```
    Intent i = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
    i.putExtras(bundle);
    Log.i("StartService","Before Wakelock");
    WakeLock lock = MyService.getLock(context);
    Log.i("StartService","After Wakelock");
    lock.acquire();
    Log.i("StartService","After Aquire");
    context.startService(i);    
    lock.release();
    Log.i("StartService","After Release");
```

All the above logs are Getting displayed. But My service is not getting called.

IntentService

```
public class MyService extends IntentService {
private static final String NAME = MyService.class.getName() + ".Lock";
private static volatile WakeLock lockStatic = null;

synchronized public static PowerManager.WakeLock getLock(Context context) {
    if (lockStatic == null) {
        PowerManager mgr = (PowerManager) context
                .getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        lockStatic = mgr.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK, NAME);
        lockStatic.setReferenceCounted(true);
    }
    return (lockStatic);
}

public MyService(String name) {
    super(name);
}

public MyService() {
    super("MyService");
}

@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    try {
        Log.i("IntentService", "In HandleIntent");
    } finally {

    }

}

}
```

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Have you declared your service in the manifest file?

Comment: If you are actually using `WakefulBroadcastReceiver`, and you use it following the documentation, you do not need your own `WakeLock`.

Comment: @Kartheek Yes, And when the device is Active Service is getting called

Comment: do you want to wake the device even it is in sleep.

Comment: @Kartheek, I want to start that Service even if the device is sleep/awake

Answer (score 0):

In the onCreate() you need to add the flags to the window. For example:

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);`
}
```

I have already posted my here [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246425/turning-on-screen-from-receiver-service/30365638#30365638)