# How do I write an android app that acts on ACTION_SCREEN_ON, without being stopped after a while?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, oneplusone

Clarification: I do not want to keep the device awake, I just want to execute my command everytime the screen is turned on.

**Short background to why I want to do this**

Some Oneplus One phones has a nasty bug where the touchscreen gets more or less unresponsive after a while. Running `cat /sys/class/input/input0/baseline_test` as root improves the situation for a while, at least for some users.
Since the problems often ocures when the phone is in sleep mode, it can be very hard to unlock the phone. So, I want to run this command every time the phone screen is activated.

> Yes, I know, I can do this with Tasker, but where is the fun in that? :)

**So, to my problem**

I am not an android developer, but I have been able to write an application that does just this. It works perfectly fine, for about an hour or so, after which it just stops working. I register the ACTION_SCREEN_ON intent in the code, since it, for some reason, is not possible to do this in the manifest. 
So, my hopefully simple question, how should I modify my application so that it is not stopped in the background. Would a service help me?

My code:

```
import ...;

public class ConfigurationActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configuration);
        registBroadcastReceiver();
    }

    public void onDestroy(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        unregisterReceiver();
    }

    private BroadcastReceiver mPowerKeyReceiver = null;

    private void registBroadcastReceiver() {
        final IntentFilter theFilter = new IntentFilter();

        theFilter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);

        mPowerKeyReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                String strAction = intent.getAction();

                if (strAction.equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {
                    Vibrator v = (Vibrator) getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
                    String[] commands = {"cat /sys/class/input/input0/baseline_test"};
                    RunAsRoot(commands);
                    v.vibrate(25);
                }
            }
        };
        getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver, theFilter);
    }

    private void unregisterReceiver() {
            getApplicationContext().unregisterReceiver(mPowerKeyReceiver);
            mPowerKeyReceiver = null;
    }

    public void RunAsRoot(String[] cmds){
        Process p = null;
        try {
            p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(p.getOutputStream());
        for (String tmpCmd : cmds) {
            try {
                os.writeBytes(tmpCmd+"\n");
                os.writeBytes("exit\n");
                os.flush();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
private void unlockScreen() {
        Window window = this.getWindow();
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
        window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
    }
```

Add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Comment: Doesn't this just prohibit the device from sleeping?

Comment: you can user this  
mWakeLock = getContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE)
    .newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());

Answer (score 0):

I had already posted an answer to a similar question Check this
[Turning on screen from receiver/service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246425/turning-on-screen-from-receiver-service/30365638#30365638)
or else check this,
[How to Lock/Unlock screen programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14352648/how-to-lock-unlock-screen-programmatically?answertab=votes#tab-top)

**Updated :**

The best way to do this is to use the [FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON) in your activity (and only in an activity, never in a service or other app component).

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
  }
```

Another way to implement this is in your application's layout XML file, by using the `android:keepScreenOn` attribute:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:keepScreenOn="true">
    ...
</RelativeLayout>
```

For more reference [click here](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html)

Comment: Perhaps my english is to bad, but my problem is NOT that I want to keep the device alive. I just want my piece of code to be executed when the screen is turned on. My code works perfectly well, but it seems like it is stopped after a while.