# How can I programmatically turn off screen in android?

Tags: android, android-powermanager

I want to turn off the screen when the user clicks a button. I am trying to do it with PowerManager class but I don't obtain good results. What is the best way to turn off the screen in android?.

I am using the code below:

> ```
>     PowerManager pm = (PowerManager)this.getSystemService(
>             Context.POWER_SERVICE);
>     PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(
>             PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
>             "");
>     wl.acquire();
> ```

But only work this code:

> ```
>     WindowManager.LayoutParams params = getWindow().getAttributes();
>     params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON;
>     params.screenBrightness = 0;
>     getWindow().setAttributes(params);
> ```

But, this code only set brightness to 0 but no turns off the screen.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Do you want turn off or lock your device?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30365638/2633909 check this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How to turn screen on and off programmatically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561320/android-how-to-turn-screen-on-and-off-programmatically)

Comment: I want to only turn off screen device no lock the screen.

Comment: @SarhadSalam i am questioning another different thing

Answer (score 3):

You can turn off screen by overriding system screen turn off time.

First get system turn off time

```
int defaultTurnOffTime =  Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 60000);
```

then put your turn off time

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, 1000);
```

and when the screen turned off, set default turn off time

```
Settings.System.putInt(getContentResolver(),Settings.System.SCREEN_OFF_TIMEOUT, defaultTurnOffTime);
```

add below permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS"/>
```

Comment: when i add the permission WRITE_SETTINGS it gives error : "Permission is only granted to system apps".