# Unlock screen - how to?

Tags: android, screen, nfc, unlock

The phone reads through NFC external sensor device. I can create service reading cyclically from NFC. Unfortunately, when the screen is locked, the NFC does not work. I need to **unlock the screen for a moment**, then it will read NFC and then **lock the screen again**. How can I do this? I also tried using AlarmManager, but I could not unlock the screen.

Comment: what do you mean by unlock?

Comment: Get screen active after it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using NFC and you are reading data wake your screen on and when NFC is done reading data use wake your screen off. Use below code

```
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
```

PowerManager.WakeLock wl = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, "My Tag");
wl.acquire();

// screen and CPU will stay awake during this section

wl.release();

Comment: Hi, I put debug information before release and I can see it. But screen is still black :) I tried to use other options like SCREEN_DIM_WAKE_LOCK, but without luck. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Correct and working answer is:

`getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_ALLOW_LOCK_WHILE_SCREEN_ON);`

with proper permission in manifest. Source: [Turning on screen from receiver/service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30246425/turning-on-screen-from-receiver-service/30365638#30365638) .