# How turn on screen via a class that does not inherit Activity

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I have a mobile app (kotlin/android studio) does not have an activity openned. This is a background service. 
My app is connected by socket with my server. Via this server, I can ask to the mobile app to start an another app. 
I found the code to do that and this works well. But I have a problem. I need to turn on my screen when I start a new app.
I have seen many solutions with different flags to setwith getWindow(). But getWidnow() works only on an activity class.

So can I turn on the screen in a class which does not inherit "Activity"?
If this is possible, can you explain me how?

Thank you.

```
var intent = contextTmp.packageManager.getLaunchIntentForPackage(packageName)
if (intent == null) {
   // Bring user to the market or let them choose an app?
   intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)
   intent.data = Uri.parse("market://details?id=$packageName")
}
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
contextTmp.startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: looks like you can manipulate screen on/off only when your app is active, and has UI

Comment: Okey, thanks! I use deprecated FULL_WAKE_LOCK for the moment to resolve my issue

Comment: Did you try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30365638/2659925

Comment: To use getWindow, I need to have an activity openned.